# Как корректно транспонировать (развернуть) строку в столбцы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имею следующий `df`:

```
qw as df rt fg gh qw fg
12 34 56 67 87 89 98 09
```

Данный `df` получаю следующим способом, выборкой строки из общего `table_df`:

```
df = table_df.loc[[18]]
```

Просьба, подсказать, как можно корректно и универсально развернуть строку, то есть привести к следующему виду:

```
qw 12
as 34
df 56
rt 67
fg 87
gh 89
qw 98
fg 09
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [методом DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
res = df.stack().reset_index(name="val").drop(columns="level_0").rename(columns={"level_1":"key"})
```

результат:

```
In [194]: res
Out[194]:
    key  val
0    qw   12
1    as   34
2    df   56
3    rt   67
4    fg   87
5    gh   89
6  qw.1   98
7  fg.1    9
```

---

если нужно получить Pandas.Series:

```
In [196]: df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[196]:
qw      12
as      34
df      56
rt      67
fg      87
gh      89
qw.1    98
fg.1     9
dtype: int64
```

или же просто транспонировать:

```
In [199]: df.T
Out[199]:
       0
qw    12
as    34
df    56
rt    67
fg    87
gh    89
qw.1  98
fg.1   9
```

Answer (score 1):

при df:

```
   qw  as  df  rt  fg  gh  qw.1  fg.1
0  12  34  56  67  87  89    98     9
```

можно воспользоваться

```
res = df.swapaxes(1,0)
```

res:

```
       0
qw    12
as    34
df    56
rt    67
fg    87
gh    89
qw.1  98
fg.1   9
```